# Clear HTML5 storage in Samsung Internet?

Tags: samsung, browser, storage, 8.0-oreo, html5

I have a problem using Samsung Internet Mobile Browser on my NoteFE running non-rooted Android 8.0.

Some websites (like mega.nz) use - what I suppose - HTML5 to store data/files offline somewhere. To access the downloaded data as file, Samsung Internet then copies the download from the internal storage to a normal file. This looks like a download, but the data is already in some kind of cache. Chrome does the same, also on PC.

Now, it seems like Samsung Internet doesn't delete this background data. However, looking at app details, I see "data" (not "cache"!) growing with each download, filling up my phones memory. It's already a couple of GB in size.

How do I reclaim this space? Only option seems to be to 'clear data', which includes all bookmarks, site info, and what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found it:

Menu - Settings - Advanced - Manage website data

This list distinguishes between normal and https, and I failed to find the item as it was saved from a page without https, while the site generally is served with https. So 2 entries, the one was the one with the big size.

Problem solved!